# How can I publish on internet my react made web page if I'm using Net Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, .net-core

I know this is a bit of a newbie question, but since I'm actually a newbie in .net-core and react, I hope you will be kind and help me out. Basically I've made a website in react by using a tutorial on internet which explained how to make it using net-core. Now I've finished it and I want to publish it on internet, but when I do it, it compiles an exe file! Can you help me? Maybe there is a way to convert the work?

Comment: How to do this is very dependent on where you're publishing TO and what tools you have. How I publish to Azure from Visual Studio is very different from FTPing my site up to GoDaddy  =)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply. I want to use ftp to publish the website, and I've tried! But like I've said, it compiled an exe when it finished uploading...can you help me please? I'm quite desperate... ^^

Comment: So you want to publish the site and copy those files up to the provider. You probably need to read documentation, as there's too many variables for a concise answer here. Some links [here](https://medium.com/dotnet-hub/publish-dot-net-core-application-and-deployment-modes-overview-fc58b3d366ff) [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem was very easy and it actually wasn't a issue that I could fix. Basically the server is running .net 4.5 instead of net-core, so I had to change the framework in order to fix the issue.